# Django unexpected characters in URL

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I am making a blog and trying to make pagination operations on post listing page. When I run my app, my URL contains unexpected characters. For example `;`

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/%5E$`

I couldn't understand why `%5E$` is there.

Here my **urls.py** (this is in blogapp):

```
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^$',views.getPosts,name="bloghome"),
    path(r'^(?P<selected_page>\d+)/?$',views.getPosts,name="bloghome"),    
    path('<slug>',views.postDetailPage,name="post_detail")
]
```

getPost function in **views.py**

```
def getPosts(request,selected_page=1):
#    latest_post = Posts.objects.get(id=1)
    posts = Posts.objects.all().order_by('-pub_date')
    pages = Paginator(posts,5) #Show 5 post per page
    try:
        returned_page = pages.page(selected_page)
    except EmptyPage:
        returned_page = pages.page(pages.num_pages)
    #content = pages.page(selected_page)    
    return render(request,'blog.html',{'page':returned_page,
                                       'posts':returned_page.object_list
                                        })
```

And finally, this bloglist page is being entered from homepage with `<a>` tag. Here it's one line of code:

```
<a href="{% url 'bloghome'%}">Blog</a>
```

Comment: Hm.. `django.urls.path`? I event can find this in my dhango 1.11. You must use `django.conf.urls.url`

Comment: Isn't ^$ is supposed to catch empty url's? How is it causing to %5E$ ?

Comment: you are mixing up the old style urls and the new path. I suggest you pick one, and if you use regex you need to use re_path
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions

Comment: this link `http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/%5E$`, did it call a specific view? if yes, which one?

Comment: Thanks everyone , as @diek said, problem was using regex with path function. After deleting regular expressions problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#django.urls.path, you need to use `re_path()` instead of `path()`, as it is interpreting `^$` literally, per zvadym's prior comment. This is new in Django 2.0, so it depends on your version.